# Is there a workaround to make DateAxis draw tick from the first date in the range

Tags: java, jfreechart

I think my question is very similar to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010228/is-there-a-workaround-to-make-dateaxis-draw-tick-from-the-first-day-of-the-week). In JFreeChart I set the bounds of  axis in a time series graph using the setRange method of DateAxis.

```
DateAxis dateAxis = (DateAxis)plot.getDomainAxis();
plot.setDomainAxis(dateAxis);
dateAxis.setRange(firstDate, lastDate);
```

However, when I use this and try to reduce the number of tick units displayed

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");
TickUnits tickUnits = new TickUnits();
tickUnits.add(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.YEAR, 1, dateFormat));
dateAxis.setStandardTickUnits(tickUnits);
```

the first tick unit shown is the next Jan 1 from the firstDate. I have seen methods like `dateAxis.setTickMarkPosition(DateTickMarkPosition.START);` but they do not achieve what I wish. I would like the first tick unit to be the firstDate I specified.

For greater clarity my question is the same problem as this [post](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116019) on another site, to which there was no reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little hack to get things working. Instead of using `firstDate` and `lastDate` to set the `dateAxis` I used `firstDate` minus one day and `lastDate` plus one day.